# How to check Internet connection in android every N seconds

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to check state of Internet connection every N seconds
how I can do it

I want to send mail when received SMS in android device

Comment: If you want to send mail only occasionally, why would you need to be continuously checking for Internet connectivity?

Comment: Why dont u check network state when you are sending email?

Comment: I want to when whatsapp sent verification code my app send SMS as email to specefic another email

Comment: my app sent verification sms  to my phone number i written a function that delete sms inbox but dont work in all device work some device and this is dangerous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check internet connection every N seconds:

Create a NetworkUtils with `isNetworkAvailable()` method that returns true or false according to connection status:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class NetworkUtils {
    public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

Create a `CheckConnection()` class that checks the connection every N seconds:

```
class CheckConnection extends TimerTask {
    private Context context;
    public CheckConnection(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
    public void run() {
        if(NetworkUtils.isNetworkAvailable(context)){
            //CONNECTED
        }else {
            //DISCONNECTED
        } 
    }
}
```

You can use `CheckConnection` class from your activity like:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
final int MILLISECONDS = 5000; //5 seconds
timer.schedule(new CheckConnection(this), 0, MILLISECONDS);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: second must be in millisecond  5000 ⇒ 5 second    final int SECONDS=5000;